# Creating a custom menu with metadata navigaion

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, css, managed-navigation, menu-item

I have been busy customising a HTML Master page. Initially, I set up (managed meta) global navigation with the appropriate snippet and showed how users can navigate to business and team pages. After a demo the consensus was to lose the *global navigation* but set up a custom branded menu (navigation) that points to selected pages or sites.

Thinking about it, I guess I could repurpose the above navigation,  global Nav menu snippet and set up  metadata navigation so my menu widget points to a set of terms News, People, Events?  I guess I just need to style this to comply with the agreed look and feel. I am also investigation the custom menu Which is part of the Office App Model v2 samples.  Hopefully this clarifies my earlier post - I welcome any comments.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your thoughts here. Do you want to manage navigation, you can do that in site settings > navigation http://<~siteCollectionURL>/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx and chose one of three types. This has nothing to do with CEWP. Please edit and rephrase your question, so we undarstand what you're trying to accomplish. Thank you!

Comment: @BennySkogberg I have 'refactored' my post as requested. The CEWP won't be needed.

Comment: That's better. It's now reopened! Good Luck!